# Count of group for null is always 0 (zero)

Tags: sql, t-sql

In TSql what is the recommended approach for grouping data containing nulls?

Example of the type of query:

```
Select Group, Count([Group]) 
From [Data] 
Group by [Group]
```

It appears that the <s>count(*) and</s> count(Group) both result in the null group displaying `0`.

Example of the expected table data:

```
Id, Group
---------
1 , Alpha
2 , Null
3 , Beta
4 , Null
```

Example of the expected result:

```
Group, Count
---------
Alpha, 1
Beta,  1
Null,  0
```

This is the desired result which can be obtained by count(Id). **Is this the best way to get this result and why does <s>count(*) and</s> count(Group) return an "incorrect" result?**

```
Group, Count
---------
Alpha, 1
Beta,  1
Null,  2
```

edit: I don't remember why I thought count(*) did this, it may be the answer I'm looking for..

Comment: Would this work? 
`Select Group, Count(IsNull([Group],1))`

Comment: @Nilesh I could just do Count(1) if I wanted to do that

Comment: Yep thats right, you can do just count(1) as well. :)

Comment: I think that you know all the things which are needed here,then why you ask this question?

Comment: @Hamidreza You know how you write a question and you figure it out while you write it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach is to use count(*) which behaves exactly like count(1) or any other constant.

The * will ensure every row is counted.

```
Select Group, Count(*) 
From [Data] 
Group by [Group]
```

The reason `null` shows `0` instead of 2 in this case is because each cell is counted as either 1 or null and `null + null = null` so the total of that group would also be null. However the column type is an integer so it shows up as `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
SELECT [group], count([group])
GROUP BY [group]
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c284/8)

Count(id) doesn't gives the expected result as mentioned in question. Gives value of 2 for group NULL

Answer (score -1):

`COUNT(*)` should work:

```
SELECT Grp,COUNT(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY Grp
```

One more solution could be following:

```
SELECT Grp, COUNT(COALESCE(Grp, ' '))
FROM tab
GROUP BY Grp
```

Here is code at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f078/5)

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
Select Group, Count(isNull(Group,0)) 
From [Data] 
Group by [Group]
```